# How to populate a self made data model in C#

Tags: c#

So basically I have a test block, which will consist of many test streets, and each test street will consist of many dut.

Below is a snippet of the three classes.

```
class DUT
    {
        public string PrimDeviceName { get; set; }
        public string Parameters { get; set; }
    }

class TestStreet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public char Revision { get; set; }
        public int XCoordinate { get; set; }
        public int YCoordinate { get; set; }

        public List<DUT> DUTList { get; private set; }

        public TestStreet ()
        {
            DUTList = new List<DUT>();
        }

        public void addDUT(DUT DeviceUnderTest)
        {
            DUTList.Add(DeviceUnderTest);
        }
    }

class TestBlock
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Revision { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<TestStreet> TestStreetList{ get; private set; }

        public TestBlock ()
        {
            TestStreetList = new List<TestStreet>();
        }

        public void addTestStreet(TestStreet street)
        {
            TestStreetList.Add(street);
        }
    }
```

There will be one Test block, which will consist of a number of Test streets, each test street will have its own properties. Then for each test street there will be a number of DUTs which will then have its own properties.
Question is whether the above codes is correct. If it is correct then how do I actually instantiate it so that I can populate it with some data? I have looked at a lot of examples but those are just simply creating a list, where my case is more complicated that I need to create a list of test streets, and for each test street I need to create a list of DUTs. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one huge list nested within a list within a list.

```
var testList = new List<TestBlock>
{
    new TestBlock
    {
        Name = "name",
        ...
        TestStreetList = new List<TestStreet>
        {
            new TestStreet
            {
                Name = "name",
                ...
                DUTList = new List<DUT>
                {
                    new DUT { PrimDeviceName = "a", ...  },
                    new DUT { PrimDeviceName = "b", ...  },
                    // repeat
                }
            },
            new TestStreet
            {
                // repeat
            }
        }
    },

    new TestBlock
    {
        // repeat
    }
};
```

Reference list items if any of these items can be duplicated i.e. a TestStreet may belong to more than one TestBlock. Even if they are not duplicated this form helps flatten the code.

```
var testBlocks = new List<TestBlock>
{
    new TestBlock { Name = "", TestStreetList = new List<TestStreet> { testStreets[0], testStreets[1] } },
    new TestBlock { Name = "", TestStreetList = new List<TestStreet> { testStreets[1] } }
};

var testStreets = new List<TestStreet>
{
    new TestStreet { Name = "", DUTList = new List<DUT> { testDut[0] } },
    new TestStreet { Name = "", DUTList = new List<DUT> { testDut[0], testDut[1] } }
};

var testDut = new List<DUT>
{
    new DUT { ... },
    new DUT { ... }
};
```

If you wanted to generate lots of these with loops you could do something like this:

```
var testBlocks = new List<TestBlock>();

for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
{
    var block = new TestBlock { ... };

    for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
    {
        var street = new TestStreet { ... };

        for (int k = 0; k < d; k++)
        {
            var dut = new DUT { ... };
            street.DUTList.Add(dut);
        }


        block.TestStreetList.Add(street);
    }

    testBlocks.Add(block);
}
```

Comment: So if one specific test street can only belong to a test block while a test block can have multiple different test streets, then I will be using the list nested within a list. 
Another question is I actually thought that i will be using this method i created in each class.  
addTestStreet(TestStreet street) doesn't seems like its used. Or is this function redundant?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another thing I would like to do is to generate a number of test streets, so i tried to use a for loop but seems like it does not allow using for loops with the var.

Comment: The Add methods are redundant unless you hide the List implementation (you expose the List properties as public now). If you always generate multiple items on an Add action then put your for loop in Add().